# Trouble using UiButton as toggle switch

Tags: ios, uibutton, toggle

I had luck with the below code using a UISwitch to toggle.
I need a UIButton to do the same. Not sure what I need to change to make that work? 
Thanks for any help!

```
- (IBAction)switchNotes:(id)sender {
    if([sender isOn]){
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[BT_color getColorFromHexString:@"#FFFF00"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:1.0f];
        }
    } else{
         NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:1.0f];

        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)switchNotes:(id)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if(sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[BT_color getColorFromHexString:@"#FFFF00"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:1.0f];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:1.0f];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi NIMO, thanks for the code! I'm guessing I'll need to set some button attributes in xib interface  builder? can you guide me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are using the isOn property which is a property of UISwitch.  According to this link [iPhone UIButton with UISwitch functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255166/iphone-uibutton-with-uiswitch-functionality) you should use the selected property of UIButton.