# Program UIButton on swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction

i have created a button on main.storyboard and i can add IBAction too. But, my aim is to make a sticky button(after you clicked once it is stayed pressed until you click it again) can somebody suggest please.

Comment: set color or image in selected state of UIbutton

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Hi, sorry i don't get it. should i do this by adding IBAction?

Comment: ya , correct, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone UIButton with UISwitch functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255166/iphone-uibutton-with-uiswitch-functionality)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yea, i think it is what i'm looking for, but it is in objective-c, can translate into swift?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-to-create-a-button-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Image in selected state of uiButton,
means you need two image one for unselected and another for selected

Comment: yup, problem solved by changing the background colour! Thanks by the way =)