# Use one UIButton same as UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiswitch

I would like to use UIButton as a switch, first tap as switch on, and second tap as switch off - and onwards.

I read a [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702194/) and made a new class `ToggleButton` as described.  By having kind advises from stack overflow, no error messages appeared on coding level. However when running the program, pressed the toggleButton and was terminated by the error "[ViewController ToggleOn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Any further coding improvements would be required?

My sample codes are follows.

```
//ToggleButton.h:

@interface ToggleButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on;
-(void)toggle;
@end


//ToggleButton.m:

#import "ToggleButton.h"
@interface ToggleButton ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *offStateImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *onStateImage;
-(void)touchedUpInside:(UIButton*) sender;
@end

@implementation ToggleButton
@synthesize on = _on;
@synthesize offStateImage = _offStateImage;
@synthesize onStateImage = _onStateImage;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];

self.offStateImage = [self imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.onStateImage = [self imageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self addTarget:self
         action:@selector(touchedUpInside:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


-(void)touchedUpInside:(UIButton*) sender
{ [self toggle]; }

-(void)toggle
{self.on = (!_on);}

-(void)setOn:(BOOL) on
{
_on = on;

if (on)
    [self setImage:self.onStateImage forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
else
    [self setImage:self.offStateImage forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
}

@end


//  ViewController.h`
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToggleButton.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *ai;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *sw;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ToggleButton *tb;
@end


//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize ai;
@synthesize sw;
@synthesize tb;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

//IBSwitch implementation

- (IBAction)SwitchChanged:(id)sender {
if(sw.on){    
[ai startAnimating];

}else{

[ai stopAnimating];}

}


//ToggleButton implementation

- (IBAction)ToggleButton:(id)sender {

if(tb.on){

    [ai startAnimating];

}else{

    [ai stopAnimating];}
}
@end
```

Comment: Please find an up-to-date tutorial. There is no reason for the `@synthesize` lines in your code.

Comment: In Image Builder you can add a `UIButton` and then set its custom class to `ToggleButton` - then an instance of your class will be created, not a generic `UIButton`

Comment: @Paulw11: Interface Builder

Comment: Doh! Yeah what he said

Answer (score 1):

Add a button on interface builder and set the custom class to **ToggleButton** (3rd tab from the left).

import ToggleButton.h in ViewController.h and add this line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ToggleButton *tb;
```

Connect `tb` and  `- (IBAction)ToggleButton:(id)sender` to Button on interface builder.

Replace this method in your ToggleButton.m class

```
-(void)toggle
{self.on = (_on);}
```

to

```
-(void)toggle
{self.on = (!_on);}
```

now it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface builder: set the custom class to `ToggleButton`, as Paulw said.

If you are creating the button in the code, you can just simply create a new instance of `ToggleButton` class in your view controller.