# Swift Adding Image to a Button

Tags: image, swift, uibutton

I want to add an image to a button, and when it is clicked, i want it to change. I'm very new to Swift so I know very little.

I have it like this:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Tip Calculator
//
//  Created by ios4 on 10/16/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 ios4. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tipAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userBillTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenOutlet: UIButton!



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        tipAmount.text = " "
      // var billDouble =  (userBillTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue


        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
       var billDouble =  NSString(string: userBillTextField.text).doubleValue
        tipAmount.text = String( stringInterpolationSegment: billDouble * 0.15)
    }

    @IBAction func tenButton(sender: UIButton)
    {



}
```

and I want the outlet called ten outlet to change to a different image called 10_selected_image from 10_unselected_image.

Any help?

Here are my instructions for this : https://s3.amazonaws.com/mmhighschool/MasterDocs/TipCalculator/TipCalculatorAppDirections.pdf

I'm currently working on stretch 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use set image for control state in your button action

```
button.setImage(image: UIImage(named: <image name>), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

If you need more info about how to make a "toggle button" this thread has a good answer to that
[How to use a UIButton as a toggle switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702194/how-to-use-a-uibutton-as-a-toggle-switch)

Answer (score 0):

For me in Swift 5 is working like:

```
boton1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "image Name"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```